# How to use JQuery in AngularJS Directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs

```
'use strict';
angular.module('simpleLiveApp'
.directive('cellar2Sidebar', ['$location', function () {
return {
templateUrl: './js/app/directives/sidebar/cellar2Sidebar.html',
restrict: 'E',
replace: true } }]);
```

I am working on a project and i want on the Directive above to add this JQuery code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".navbar-toggle").click(function(){
            $(".fa").toggleClass("fa-indent fa-outdent");
        });
});
```

Comment: don't use jQuery with angularjs; directives already use jQLite

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30616120/2801860

Comment: this code won't run. `angular.module('simpleLiveApp'` <-- missing `)` here

Comment: That snippet of jQuery code does not translate well to a directive. Instead describe what you want the `cellar2Sidebar` component to do. Implement it by using the [`ng-click` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) and the [`ng-class` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) in the HTML of the component. For more information, see [“Thinking in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular has a builtin service called $document.
it is a lite version of jQuery called jQLite.

which contains .ready
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

or if you have a new version of angular/ want to support one
(deprecated, use angular.element(callback) instead of angular.element(document).ready(callback))

from the documentation...